# Oracle UTL_MATCH.Jaro_wrinkler function performance

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a requirement to compare millions of records in one resultset with another resultset of 50000 records.
so a Plsql code is written to match the string in both recordsets.The performance of this function is very slow.

we have written code similar to this in Oracle plsql.

```
for rec in cur loop for rec1 in cur1 loop utl_match.jaro_wrinkler_similarity(rec.string1,rec1.string2);end loop;end loop;
```

Please help how can we improve the performance of below match.

```
for rec in cur loop for rec1 in cur1 looputl_match.jaro_wrinkler_similarity(rec.string1,rec1.string2);end loop;end loop;
```

Comment: You're in a bad situation if you have to blindly match this many rows with a non-equality like this. The first thing I'd suggest is find another way to filter down the candidate matches without the function. Is there another column you can use to narrow down the possibilities? Can you at least match on the first character or first two characters?  Once you get it as narrow as you can, if you need brute force, create your proc with a thread id input and use a modulus to split up work so you can have 10, 20, etc... threads of this going on, dividing the workload.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be *fast*; mind you, you're producing Cartesian product of *millions of rows* x 50.000 rows. It just takes time.

(By the way, code you posted is invalid; you have to do *something* with value you calculated - store it into some variable, display it ... whatever. It can't just *be* there, all alone).

However, if you explained what exactly you're looking for, perhaps there can be a different (faster?) option than calculating similarity.

For example, if you wanted to know whether one string exists in another, you could've used `instr(first_string, second_string) > 0`.

Another option is the `soundex` function, e.g. `... where soundex(first_string) = soundex(second_string)`.

There might be other options, but - as I said - you have to provide some more information about the problem, illustrated with some sample data and rules which have to be applied in order to get desired result.

---

Instead of nested loops:

```
begin
  for c1 in (select ename from emp) loop
    for c2 in (select dname from dept d) loop
      dbms_output.put_line(c1.ename||' '|| c2.dname ||' '|| utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(c1.ename, c2.dname));
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

see whether actual join helps:

```
begin
  for c1 in (select e.ename, d.dname from emp e cross join dept d) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(c1.ename||' '|| c1.dname ||' '|| utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(c1.ename, c1.dname));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

---

Have a look at this [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/ords/asktom.search?tag=performace-issue-with-sql-in-the-view-using-utl-matchjaro-winkler-similarity) discussion; read it carefully, especially what mathguy and Barbara Boehmer have said.

Comment: The requirement is to match data using only Jaro wrinkler function and if the match is greater than 90 insert into a match table. I have just added a sample code how we match the strings. but since the match is to be done with millions of rows it takes 3 hrs to 4 hrs.so Is there a better way to improve performance of this utl_match.Jaro_wrinkler function matching.

Comment: There are no shortcuts here, then. If you really have to match every value from one table to every value from another table, with nothing else to help (read: apply filter on any table involved), it'll take time. Maybe you could, though, try to rewrite code not to use nested loops but actual join. See edited answer for example.